# how to perform zoom in effect on NSview?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-animation

I have a NSView that shows some drawing. User can zoom in the drawing.

Now, i just redraw the NSView when it is zoomed in.

What i want to do is to show a zoom effect before redrawing.

How can i do that?

Comment: How exactly are you zooming in? Are you using a `NSScrollView` or are you just redrawing the view's contents?

Comment: I am redrawing the view contents. What i want to do is to zoom the view and after the fast zoom is finished, redraw the view

Comment: Have you found the solution?